# google cloud bigquery costing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-billing

We are using bigquery for storing our data. Google cloud charge us a lot for billing we actual store data approx 2 GB current month but in the billing for current they charge us for 200 TB with they are saying resource.

[image]

We are not querying any thing on bigquery and we are not using any public dataset for our use.

Pls help us to figure out this charges for what is it for storing public dataset ?

Comment: While I sympathise, the best course of action is to open a ticket with customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a high BigQuery API traffic, I believe the 197.10 Tebibyte usage for BigQuery Analyisis is from there if you are not querying anything via UI.

To get the exact usage for each BigQuery job, you can use [BigQuery API Jobs:list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) and get in the response fields such as *totalBytesProcessed* and *totalBytesBilled*.

Now with this information in hand, you can calculate the charges. The price is [$5 per TB beyond your first 1 TB of data processed in a month](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing). In your case:  (197.10 - 1) * 5= $ 980.5

Comment: how about following statement `We are not querying any thing on bigquery`? :o) I think this was a core of question!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, I was able to inspect their project, and they have a lot of BigQuery API requests. I think they are just not querying anything via bigquery UI.

Comment: as expected  - :o) - so, I think this what is important to explain to OP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my answer. Hopefully it is more clear now.